# Redirect Parent of iframe on different domain - alternative logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I was wondering if anyone could help find a solution to a particular problem:

I have a form that I'd like to embed in a few different web sites, on different domains.  This form  needs to redirect to PayPal.  The plan was to embed this form in an iframe, making it easy to update etc, plus minimal code to embed.  However, due to same origin policy I cannot use `parent.location.href = "http://PaypalPaymentAddress.com";` to redirect the form.  I don't want to process the payment in the frame (Paypal anyway forbids this)...

The only way around this I can think of is having a script run and render the form into the parent page, calling a web service or so to get the HTML, but that would obviously be a lot of work!

Any ideas how I might set this up to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the target-attribute  `"_parent"` for the form, when it will be submitted the target-URL will be loaded into the parent-window.

Comment: One snag though... I have server side validation running, and I don't want the redirect to happen if the form is invalid.  Is there a way you can prevent this happening?

Comment: you may use ajax to perform the serverside validation in the background and submit the form when the validation was successful.

Comment: My server side validation is also transaction based, e.g. checks quantity of items before processing... submitting the form blind after an AJAX check would leave it open to hacking.  However, I will try sending back a small HTML page with a blank form that submits to parent (similar to using the javascript redirect), and submit this form with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

My final method was based on Dr. Molle's answer, but slightly different.  I have explained it here in case it is useful to anyone else:

I set up the form to submit normally, allowing all my server validation etc to only fire once.  If the form submitted successfully (passes the server validation), a small html client page, containing an empty form was posted back.

This empty form has a post action of the parent page URL, and a target = "Parent" and on the client "document ready", a jQuery method submits the form, causing the parent page to reload.

A link with a "_top" attribute is also provided in case scripts are disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#redirectForm").submit();
    });
</script>
<a href="{parentpageurl}" id="redirectLink" target="_top">click here if not redirected automatically</a><br />

<form id="redirectForm" method="POST" action="{parentpageurl}" target="_parent">

</form>
```

One way of getting round the "Same Origin Policy", as this method works cross domain.  Hope that helps somebody!